# How to write a template?

Tags: c++, templates, heap

i need to write a template with Nodes containing data with 2 data structures : a map and a minimum heap, both got the same nodes in it and every 2 same nodes are connected.
the problem is that i need the heap to know the node fields for the heapify for example, and i don't know what's the right way to do so, friends? public fields in Node? writing the Node inside the heap? using getters and setters?
thanks all for your help.

Comment: Uhm, dude? Same as [how to implement minheap using template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745194/how-to-implement-minheap-using-template)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to implement minheap using template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745194/how-to-implement-minheap-using-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a linked list might be laid out like this:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
namespace detail 
{
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node* previous;
    Node* next;
    //constructors and other things that might help
};
}

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    detail::Node<T>* head;
public:
    //all it does    
};
}
```

There is no particular reason to hide the Node struct from the user or the LinkedList class (putting it into a detail namespace should be more than enough): LinkedList needs it and the Node itself is pretty much useless to the user. All encapsulation is up to LinkedList to achieve: it just shouldn't give out it's head (or any other `Node*`).

Comment: You should only put class Node in the detail namespace thou.